# Unable to check MAC Address from JAR

Tags: java, windows, macos, ethernet

I have the following code, my problem is that when i run the code from netbeans it runs fine. BUT when i run the code from a jar file it doesn't work fine. I want the JAR to close it MAC doesn't match, BUT STILL IT KEEPS ON RUNNING
Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
          String[] macArray = new String[1000];
  macArray[0] = "74 E5 43 23 F1 B4 ";
  macArray[1] = "74 E5 43 24 5F 18 ";
  int i=0;
  String[] current = new String[1000];

 Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (interfaces.hasMoreElements())
{
  NetworkInterface nif = interfaces.nextElement();
  byte[] lBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
  StringBuffer lStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

  if (lBytes != null)
  {
    for (byte b : lBytes)
    {
      lStringBuffer.append(String.format("%1$02X ", new Byte(b)));
    }
  }
  current[i]=lStringBuffer.toString();
  System.out.println(lStringBuffer);
  i++;

  //System.out.println(lStringBuffer)
}

for(; i<1000; i++){
    current[i]= "" + 0;
}
int te=0;
for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
    for(int k=0; k<1000; k++){
        if(current[j].equals(macArray[k])){
            System.out.println("WOW!!!");
            te=1;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(current[j]);
}
if(te!=1){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
    System.exit(0);

}
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FormTTS().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought that maybe there is some problem in my code so i tried this one, but the problem remains the same:

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
        int d, check=0;
        String[] macArray;//array of allowed mac adresses


        macArray = new String[1000];
        macArray[0] = "74-E5-43-23-F1-B4";

        //macArray[1] = "00-00-00-00-00-00";

        //MAC CHECKING
        InetAddress ip;
    try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
//      System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        //System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        //System.out.println(sb.toString());
                String a=(sb.toString());
                //String b="74-E5-43-23-F1-B4";

                for(d=0; d<macArray.length; d++){
                if(a.equals(macArray[d])){
                    check=1;
                    break;
                }
                }

                if(check==1){
                    System.out.println("Success: Congrats, you are registered");
                }
                if(check!=1){
                    System.out.println("Registration Required");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
                    System.exit(0);

                }    
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


       public void run() {
                new FormTTS().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: so what are the values being stored in your `current` array.  Is there any?  Are they maybe just different case?

Comment: @user2310289 Current array stores the mac addresses of the local machine and checks if they match with the one i specified and if they are different it should exit but it doesnt